# zabbix agent2 inside docker for monitoring other containers

Tags: docker, zabbix

I have a VM on which docker is installed and all services are already in containers. Zabbix is a separate VM and zabbix itself is also in containers.

I tried to raise a docker container with zabbix agent2 so that it monitors containers on the first server, but the zabbix says that docker.service is not active.

All I found was that you need to "put a privileged mode and everything will work." But the couple doesn't work... ([screnshot compilation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rli1Y.jpg))

docker-compose file (vm1):

```
version: '3.5'
services:
 zabbix-agent:
  image: ${AGENT_IMAGE}
#  profiles:
#   - full
#   - all
  ports:
   - "10050:10050"
  volumes:
   - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
   - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
   - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
   - ${ZBX_FOLDER}/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d:/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d:ro
   - ${ZBX_FOLDER}/var/lib/zabbix/modules:/var/lib/zabbix/modules:ro
   - ${ZBX_FOLDER}/var/lib/zabbix/enc:/var/lib/zabbix/enc:ro
   - ${ZBX_FOLDER}/var/lib/zabbix/ssh_keys:/var/lib/zabbix/ssh_keys:ro
  deploy:
   resources:
    limits:
      cpus: '0.2'
      memory: 128M
    reservations:
      cpus: '0.1'
      memory: 64M
   mode: global
  env_file:
   - ${ZBX_ENVFILES}/.env_agent
  privileged: true
  pid: "host"
  networks:
   my_net:
    aliases:
     - zabbix-agent
     - zabbix-agent-passive
     - zabbix-agent-alpine
  stop_grace_period: 5s
  labels:
   com.zabbix.description: "Zabbix agent"
   com.zabbix.company: "Zabbix LLC"
   com.zabbix.component: "zabbix-agentd"
   com.zabbix.os: "alpine"

networks:
  my_net:
    name: my_network
    external: true
```

envfile:

```
ZBX_FOLDER=/path/to/zabbix/data
ZBX_ENVFILES=/path/to/envfiles/zabbix_env

AGENT_IMAGE=zabbix/zabbix-agent2:alpine-6.2-latest

COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=zabbix
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work by adding zabbix user to docker group inside the container.

Just add this to your docker compose file:

```
group_add:
 - "984"
```

Replace 984 with gid of docker group.

You already made docker.sock available inside the container and it's privileged so it should work.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it later, there's no time right now.